# insert directly or via a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am using sql server and winforms for my application. data would be inserted every minute into the database tables by pressing a button on a Form.

for this, I am using the INSERT query.

But if I create a procedure and include the same insert query in it, then would it be more efficient, what would be the difference then?

Comment: "data would be inserted every minute ... by pressing a button on a Form".  The "every minute" part sounds dubious.  Why not take the human interaction out of the picture, and simply trigger the insert with an automated timer?  If you can't automate it (because a human has to create the data), are they required to do this every minute, or is this simply about how often you'll be getting requests?

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham--i meant that the application would manage the sales of a large scale firm, so as an item is sold,immediately its entry would be entered by the human into the database. and by every minute i meant that as it is a large scale firm so its obvious that it sells items very frequently

Answer (score 3):

Using stored procedures is more secure

Comment: Can you provide more information please, in what way it is more secure?

Comment: If you allow the user to call a stored proc, that user needs only EXECUTE permission on that stored proc - that user does not need to have INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE permissions on the underlying table(s) which makes it safer (if that user should start up Access or Excel and try to use the database directly)

Comment: It's more about web development, but user can use SQL Injection technique. You need to sanitize your imput before using user's entered data in your insert statement. Stored procedures receive all user's input as params so SQL injection is impossible. Moreover, stored procedures can be changed in databese without needing to recompile the application. And they can benefit from various SQL optimizations

Answer (score 3):

A stored procedure would generally be quicker as the query plan is stored and does not need to be created for each call. If this is a simple insert the difference would be minimal.

A stored procedure can be run with execute permissions which is more secure than giving insert permissions to the user.

Comment: Not really true - once a parametrized query is parsed, its execution plan is cached, too, so there's really no significant speed advantage to a stored proc anymore

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by 'efficient'.

- Execution time - if you're only saving to the database only every couple of seconds then any speed difference between SPs and INSERT is most likely insignificant. If the volume is especially high you would probably set up something like a command queue on the server before fine-tuning at this level.
- Development time

  - using INSERT means you can write your SQL directly in your codebase (in a repository or similar). I've seen that described as poor design, but I think that as long as you have integration tests around the query there's no real problem
  - Stored Procedures can be more difficult to maintain  - you need to have a plan to deploy the new SP to the database. Benefits are that you can implement finer-grained security on the database itself (as @b-rain and @mark_s have said) and it is easy to decide between INSERT and UPDATE within the SP, whereas to do the same in code means making certain assumptions.

Personally (at the moment) I use inline SQL for querying and deleting, and stored procedures for inserting. I have a script and a set of migration files that I can run against the production database to deploy table and SP changes, which seems to work pretty well. I also have integration tests around both the inline SQL and the SP calls. If you go for inline SQL you definitely should use parameterised queries, it helps against SQL injection attacks and it is also easier to read and program.

Comment: i have a simple query: INSERT INTO items values() --this would be run be a human by clicking a button on the winform  , but very frequently, i.e. every minute.  so should use this query only or give it inside the procedure

Comment: By parameterized query you refer to this type of query,  DECLARE @itemname  SET @itemname =textbox1.Text;   "Insert Into items Values(@itemname )"    .  Please give me an example , as i think am wrong here

Comment: @sqlchild yes that is wrong. You declare the command like `var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO items VALUES(@itemname)"` then add the parameters using `cmd.Parameters.Add()`. Try googling for 'c# parameterized query'.

Comment: @sqlchild and if you're only inserting items and never updating them (which sounds ok for a front-end sales system) I would probably use an inline query, and consider changing to an SP if the needs change.

Comment: thanks a lot sir, yes my application is for medical stores , so you prefer using parameterized queries, also, in cmd.Parameters.Add(textBox1.Text) --- in this way i would add the parameters

Answer (score 1):

If your DBA is even *allowing* you to do this without a stored procedure I'd be very suspicious...

Comment: sir, you mean that the insert should be via a stored procedure and not directly via the insert query. as the end users would insert data from the winform application into the database.